# как склонировать DIV с применением JQuery, потом изменить данные в блоке и вставить в контейнер?

Tags: jquery

клонировать получается но изменить тот блок и обратно запушить как сделать? Спасибо!

```js
var clone = $('.grid-item').filter( ':first' ).clone(true);
                        
                      clone.find('.post-image a').attr('https://ru.stackoverflow.com/').appendTo('.blog-grid');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let cl = $('.grid-item:first').clone(true);
cl.find('.post-image a')
  .attr('href', 'ru.meta.stackoverflow.com')
  .html('ru.meta.stackoverflow.com');
$('.blog-grid').append(cl);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="blog-grid">
  <div class="grid-item">
    <div class="post-image">
      <a href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com">ru.stackoverflow.com</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

не используйте зарезервированные слова в качестве имён переменных (clone etc.)

Comment: С каких это пор `clone` стало *"зарезервированным словом"*?

Comment: с тех пор, как стало именем метода.

Comment: Это уж дудки :) Почитайте, что есть зарезервированные слова (`var`, `let` и т.д.), а то мне прямо жалко Вас: видимо, у Вас на подбор имени переменной уходит очень много времени, ибо все удобоваримые имена какие-то черти уже разобрали под названия методов и свойств :)

Comment: @Kir_Antipov Не стоит язвить, это здесь не к чему. То, о чём вы упамянули - зарезервированные Ключевые слова. В общем случае любое слово, что-либо обозначающее в данной среде разработки, будет резервированным. Это не означает системный запрет на использование, как в случае с ключевыми словами. Но такое необдуманное именование переменных ухудшает читаемость и разбор кода (цена поддержки) и может в дальнейшем даже приводить к разного родам ошибкам. И да, обычно я и мои коллеги имена переменным даём обдуманно, это часть разработки, как бы смешно оно вам не казалось.

Comment: То есть `cl` - это *"обдуманное имя переменной"*? Мы тут не в С на гласных экономим, мы пытаемся писать читаемый код. Когда я (как и любой другой нормальный человек) вижу переменную с именем `clone`, я сразу понимаю, что был какой-то объект и его склонировали/скопировали, так что если я внесу в него изменения, это не отразится на первоначальной сущности. Что же мне приходит в голову при виде `cl`? Да чуть больше, чем ничего, потому что этот нейминг ничего не говорит о том, что за ним скрывается, только если не ты сам его придумал и *помнишь*, что он означает.

Comment: И да, я не язвил. Просто Вам, похоже, и правда тяжело приходится с такой моделью: только придумал название для переменной, чтобы оно зачем-то не пересекалось с именами методов/свойств во всех подключённых библиотеках, как коллеги подключили в проект новую, где это имя уже "занято" ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: `Зарезервированные слова == ключевые слова == зарезервированные ключевые слова (aka масло масляное)`. Если я создал функцию с именем `bubblegum`, это не значит, что я (такой вот Великий и Ужасный) зарезервировал это слово, так что больше никто не имеет права использовать это имя в своей кодовой базе

Comment: Это просто название метода, не больше.